# SocketException and EOFException while connecting to web server using HttpsUrlConnection in Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, socketexception, eofexception

My clients get sometimes two exceptions SocketException: Socket is closed and EOFException when I try to connect with the soap web server.

I use this code:

```
private String callWebService(String soapAction, String envelope, boolean runInBackground) {
    if (soapAction == null || envelope == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int retry = RETRY_COUNT;
    int count = 0;
    boolean shouldRetry = false;

    if (mShouldRetryWhenError == false) {
        retry = 1;
    }

    while (count < retry) {
        count++;
        URL address = null;

        try {
            address = new URL(URL);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        boolean errorOcurred = false;

        HttpsURLConnection connection = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        InputStream responseStream = null;

        try {
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            connection = (HttpsURLConnection)address.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", NAMESPACE + "#" + soapAction);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            }

            connection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT);
            connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(envelope.length());
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            errorOcurred = true;
            shouldRetry = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorOcurred = true;

            Utils.sendErrorReport(TAG + " - error while openning connection: " + e.toString(), mContext);

            if (!runInBackground) {
                handleError(null);
            }
        }

        if (errorOcurred) {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            if (!shouldRetry) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        try {
            outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            errorOcurred = true;
            shouldRetry = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorOcurred = true;

            if (!(e instanceof UnknownHostException)) {
                Utils.sendErrorReport(TAG + " - no output stream could be created: " + e.toString(), mContext);
            }

            if (!runInBackground) {
                handleError(null);
            }
        }

        if (errorOcurred) {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            if (!shouldRetry) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        Writer out = null;

        try {
            out = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "utf-8");
            out.write(envelope);
            out.flush();
            //out.close();

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode >= 300) {
                InputStream errorStream = connection.getErrorStream();
                String error = readDataFromInputStream(errorStream);
                Utils.sendErrorReport(TAG + ": responseCode " + responseCode + ", error: " + error, mContext);

                if (errorStream != null) {
                    errorStream.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            errorOcurred = true;
            shouldRetry = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorOcurred = true;

            Utils.sendErrorReport(TAG + " - writing to the output stream: " + e.toString(), mContext);

            if (!runInBackground) {
                handleError(null);
            }
        }

        if (errorOcurred || connection.getContentLength() <= 0) {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }

            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            if (!shouldRetry) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        try {
            responseStream = connection.getInputStream();
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            errorOcurred = true;
            shouldRetry = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorOcurred = true;

            Utils.sendErrorReport(TAG + " - input stream could not be created: " + e.toString(), mContext);

            if (!runInBackground) {
                handleError(null);
            }
        }

        if (errorOcurred) {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }

            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            if (!shouldRetry) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        String response = null;

        try {
            response = readDataFromInputStream(responseStream);
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            shouldRetry = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Utils.sendErrorReport(TAG + " - reading data from the input stream: " + e.toString(), mContext);

            if (!runInBackground) {
                handleError(null);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }

                if (outputStream != null) {
                    outputStream.close();
                }

                if (responseStream != null) {
                    responseStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        if (!shouldRetry) {
            return response;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

SocketException takes place here:

```
outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
```

or

```
response = readDataFromInputStream(responseStream);
```

EOFException takes place here:

```
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

Does somebody know what is wrong here?